# Can I improve download-speed by connecting two 4g-routers?

Tags: networking, router, speed

I have mobile Internet at home with one Huawei B593 4g-router. When it works it's pretty fast, around 17 Mbits/s down, but the service is unstable and I would frankly like it even faster. If i get one more internetsubscription so that I have two routers, each with its own simcard and subscription, would it be possible to connect them in a way that I got double download-speed and redundancy (if one malfunctioned the other would still be working).
I would be willing to build a new computer to get this to work so just tell me what i would need. Thanks in advance.

Andy